# Why can't I override a javax.validation.ValidationFactory when deploying mule app to CloudHub?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

I'm trying to load `javax.validation.ValidationFactory` from a library containing the `javax.validation` package (retrieved from jboss.org).  I see that the library is included when I export the Mule Studio Project to a zip file, so I'm assuming it is also exported when I deploy the application to CloudHub (all of my other 3rd party jars have deployed with minimal trouble).

Unfortunately, I get a `ClassNotFound` error. I've tried overriding the class definition using `loader.override=javax.validation.ValidatorFactory` in the `mule-deploy.properties`, but I get an error in CloudHub saying that I can't override a system package. I thought the above override would only override the given class, asking CloudHub to look within the deployed application for a class definition rather than from the CloudHub supplied libraries.

As a side note, searching through a copy of the Mule Standalone server, I don't see `javax.validation.ValidationFactory` anywhere. Can anyone tell me why I can't force the load of this one class using `loader.override`?

Comment: Is this error still happening with current versions?